# Exporting model to csv

Tags: javascript, csv, sapui5

I'm trying to make an export of my model which consists out of employees, some properties and a Date.

**Visualisation of my model**

```
var myModel= {
  employees: [{
    pentagram: oMyData.Pentagram,
    records: [{
      Date: oMyData.Date,
      GC: oMyData.Lunch,
      CheckIn: oMyData.CheckedIn,
      CheckOut: oMyData.CheckedOut
    }]
  }]
};
```

**Purpose of my application**

My app is used to log which employee is in the building by letting them check in and out at the front door. This is registered to a HanaXS database. Each day when an employee checks in, a record is created with the corresponding properties. So if the decide not to eat at the office, they will click on the GC button (which stands for 'no consumption' in dutch).

So in a nutshell. Each employee has their own record per date in the database.

**What do I want to do**

I want to make an excel sheet which will cover a month.
The most left column will cover the names of the employee's (Pentagram). After that all the columns will be a day  in the corresponding month in chronological order.

The content should be an X when they pressed the GC button. Otherwise the cell should be empty.

**My problem**

I have no clue how to get the dates as columns while keeping the binding with the employees. I've already searched a lot on exporting of the model and of tables but nothing is actually near to what I need.

If anyone has some experience or done this before I would be really gratefull for some help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the following libraries

```
'sap/ui/core/util/Export',
'sap/ui/core/util/ExportTypeCSV',
```

This is the sample code you can refer to suit your needs

```
generateExcel: function(oData, that) {
            var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(oData); //oData is the model data which is binding to the table

            var oTable = this.getViewById("yourTableName").getTable();
            var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
            var aItems = oTable.getItems();
            var aTemplate = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++) {

                    var oColumn = {
                        name: aColumns[i].getHeader().getText(),
                        template: {
                            content: {
                                path: null
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    if (aItems.length > 0) {
                        oColumn.template.content.path = aItems[0].getCells()[i].getBinding("text").getPath();
                    }
                    aTemplate.push(oColumn);

            }

            var oExport = new Export({
                // Type that will be used to generate the content. Own ExportType’s can be created to support other formats
                exportType: new ExportTypeCSV({
                    separatorChar: ",",
                    charset: "utf-8"
                }),
                // Pass in the model created above
                models: oModel,
                // binding information for the rows aggregation
                rows: {
                    path: "/results"
                },
                // column definitions with column name and binding info for the content
                columns: aTemplate
            });
            oExport.saveFile().always(function() {
                this.destroy();
            });
        }
```

Hi you can use custom formatter for columns depending on types like below an example

```
var oColumn = {
                        name: aColumns[i].getHeader().getText(),
                        template: {
                            content: {
                                path: null,
                                formatter: function(value) {
                                    if (value instanceof(Date)) {
                                        //Convert to user date format
                                        var oFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance({
                                            style: "short"
                                        });
                                        value = oFormat.format(value);

                                    } else {

                                        value = (value === null) ? "" : value;

                                    }
                                    return value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will this make sure that in each (date) column the corresponding value of GC will be inserted? So for example, in column '31-08-2018' will contain all value's of GC for all employees?

Comment: I've updated code to show what you can do with columns using formatter depending on type you expecting

Comment: If you can add your code here and I can try help out